# VS2010 test project for x64 projects: "unable to load test container"

Tags: visual-studio-2010, unit-testing, vs-unit-testing-framework

I created a C++ test project which references other projects & getting the error:

```
"Unable to load the test container ... or one of its dependencies. If you build your test project assembly as a 64 bit assembly, it cannot be loaded. When you build your test project assembly, select "Any CPU" for the platform. To run your tests in 64 bit mode on a 64 bit processor, you must change your test settings in the Hosts tab to run your tests in a 32 bit process."
```

I set "Run test in 64 bit process" in the test settings. I tried building the test project as x64 and mixed platforms (Any CPU available only for .NET), checked dependencies of the projects themselves (third party are x64). But always the same error. So is this possible & what am I missing?

Thank you

Comment: Nothing distinguishes your question from the many other ones that ask about this error message.  If you have no idea what is going on then use SysInternals' Process Monitor.  The trace shows you which executable files are being loaded.  Use dumpbin.exe /headers on all of them to verify your assumptions.  Practice first with a "hello world" test to see what you'd expect to happen.

Comment: @Hans thanks for your reply. I created a test project & ran dumpbin for the proj & testing proj. In the output was "8664 machine (x64)" & "large (>2GB) addresses" for both. Is there something else I should look for in the dump? "Other questions that ask about this message": Can you please point me to one? remark: my project is pure unmanaged c++ if that matters. Thank you very much.